# MS SQL big load

Tags: sql-server, nosql

I am making slot games. I am inserting each spin result into `Logs` table.
A player is allowed to click spin multiple times/sec
So assume if 10,000 users are playing the game, a huge amount of data is getting populated into the table.

Later we show the result via the website to the player.
We are using the below query but the page takes too long to load the data.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY datetime desc) as rowNum 
FROM Logs WHERE username=$username and datetime >= $startdate and datetime <= $enddate) sub 
where rowNum between $startindex AND $endindex
```

Schema of the `Logs` Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GameLogs](
 [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
 [username] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL, 
 [gamename] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL, 
 [bet] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL, 
 [win] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL, 
 [datetime] [datetime] NOT NULL, 
 [gamelog] [nvarchar](3072) NULL 
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Hope it's due to the huge amount of data in the table.
Some reference said about using NoSQL.

Comment: did you try indexing RowNum?

Comment: Can you please provide the schema for the Table `Logs`

Comment: Thank you for your reply
I already index rowNum.

It's my table schema.
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GameLogs](
 [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [username] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [gamename] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
 [bet] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
 [win] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
 [datetime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [gamelog] [nvarchar](3072) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: one of my friend offer ms sql partition, one offer nosql.
Please let me know your idea.
I need fast insert and also fast select of table.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the pre execution plan in SSMS. Then, if indexes are necessary, there will be green text at the top of the plan describing those indexes.